# SElinux security context public_content_t for vsftpd

Tags: linux, ftp, selinux

My understanding of SElinux context `public_content_t` is as

`public_content_t` *is required for files shared via a FTP server unless associated with a user home directory*

Here is my question

Does `user` include FTP anonymous user `ftp`? If I have created a file owned by `ftp:ftp` and save it to `/var/ftp/pub` does it mean it is associated with a user account ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SELinux labels don't care about the username or userid. There is a helpful mapping of default labels to paths, which you can look at by running:

```
semanage fcontext -l
```

In your case, we are interested in the `/var/ftp` directory:

```
# semanage fcontext -l | grep '/var/ftp'
/var/ftp(/.*)?                                     all files          system_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0
/var/ftp/bin(/.*)?                                 all files          system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0
/var/ftp/etc(/.*)?                                 all files          system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0
/var/ftp/lib(64)?(/.*)?                            all files          system_u:object_r:lib_t:s0
/var/ftp/lib(64)?/ld[^/]*\.so(\.[^/]*)*            regular file       system_u:object_r:ld_so_t:s0
```

From this output, you'll see that excepting `/var/ftp/bin`, `/var/ftp/etc`, and `/var/ftp/lib(64)?`, all files placed in `/var/ftp` will be assigned `public_content_t` label. So, if you create a new file in `/var/ftp/pub`, it will be labelled `public_content_t` regardless of whether you did this as user root, ftp, bob, etc.

Comment: if a file owned by `ftp:ftp` and it is in `/var/ftp/pub` directory, does that mean it is associated with a user home directory ? I guess not because security context of normal user account is `user_home_t` so looks like `ftp` is considered different to normal system users, that is what I am trying to find out.